# Why I am getting the HttpHostConnectException

Tags: java, android, exception

I am using the following code in android virtual Machine

```
 try{
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/ReadingFromServer.php");
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
       is = entity.getContent();
       }catch(Exception e){
           Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
      }
```

I am getting the HttpHostConnectException. Dont know why? I have changed the address in the url from 127.0.0.1 to 10.0.2.2 but still getting that exception. I have wamp server installed in my computer and the file "ReadingFromServer.php" is placed in "www" folder.

Here is the complete stack trace

```
05-20 20:40:32.218: W/System.err(681): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2 refused
05-20 20:40:32.248: W/System.err(681):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
05-20 20:40:32.258: W/System.err(681):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-20 20:40:32.268: W/System.err(681):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-20 20:40:32.278: W/System.err(681):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-20 20:40:32.288: W/System.err(681):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-20 20:40:32.298: W/System.err(681):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-20 20:40:32.308: W/System.err(681):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-20 20:40:32.318: W/System.err(681):  at com.test.TestProjectActivity.onCreate(TestProjectActivity.java:56)
05-20 20:40:32.328: W/System.err(681):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-20 20:40:32.338: W/System.err(681):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-20 20:40:32.348: W/System.err(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-20 20:40:32.358: W/System.err(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-20 20:40:32.368: W/System.err(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-20 20:40:32.378: W/System.err(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-20 20:40:32.388: W/System.err(681):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 20:40:32.398: W/System.err(681):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 20:40:32.408: W/System.err(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-20 20:40:32.418: W/System.err(681):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 20:40:32.428: W/System.err(681):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 20:40:32.438: W/System.err(681):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-20 20:40:32.448: W/System.err(681):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-20 20:40:32.448: W/System.err(681):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 20:40:32.468: W/System.err(681): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-20 20:40:32.488: W/System.err(681):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:181)  
05-20 20:40:32.498: W/System.err(681):  ... 21 more
05-20 20:40:32.508: W/System.err(681): Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-20 20:40:32.528: W/System.err(681):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:573)
05-20 20:40:32.538: W/System.err(681):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
05-20 20:40:32.548: W/System.err(681):  at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:663)
05-20 20:40:32.558: W/System.err(681):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:807)
05-20 20:40:32.578: W/System.err(681):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
05-20 20:40:32.578: W/System.err(681):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
05-20 20:40:32.588: W/System.err(681):  ... 21 more
05-20 20:40:32.598: W/System.err(681): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-20 20:40:32.628: W/System.err(681):  at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
05-20 20:40:32.658: W/System.err(681):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:181)
05-20 20:40:32.658: W/System.err(681):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:558)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exception message telling you?

Comment: See if there is an overload on the Log class that has an method that you can pass it the entire exception (e), that way it will likely log a stack trace as well. Log4j does this, I imagine Android has something similar.

Comment: Use `e.printStacktrace();` function to get the whole exception with more details and update your question with the whole stracktrace.

Comment: TextProjectActivity is the name of my Activity class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you declare the Internet permission in the AndroidManifest.xml?

You need to put the following into the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest> 
  ...
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: yes i declared the internet permission in the AndroidManifest.xml, but it is not working for me.

Comment: Double check the permission. Your error really looks like a missing permission.

Comment: Now by adding the permission , i am getting android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. What is it now?

Comment: You should do the networking in an AsyncTask: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Or you could make targetSDKVersion lower than 11.

Comment: I have solved the problem by adding these two tags to my manifest:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Answer (score 1):

internet permission to your application by adding this under `manifest` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

otherwise Android will block internet traffic from your app